# Use a concrete core drill (6") on plaster lath?

Tags: plaster, ducts

I'm installing a range hood vent through a double brick wall, so I need to rent a core drill and 6" core bit. Would it be possible/advisable to use the same bit to cut through the plaster and lath (NOT drywall) on the interior wall? I would do it handheld (vs mounted as with the exterior wall) and go really slow.

Comment: What type of lath? A core drill is basically a grinding tool. It's virtually impossible to grind through wood with it, and metal wouldn't be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will bounce and chatter as the wood laths move.

So I would look at stitch drilling around the circle by hand with a small drill and trimming up after. Lath with plaster is **difficult** to work at the best of times.

Comment: I've made plenty of cuts through plaster & lath with a jigsaw to install boxes for switches and outlets. After picking up an oscillating saw, that made the cuts _much_ easier. For a round hole, I'd suggest sticking with the jig saw. It shouldn't need to be a super pretty hole - the range hood will cover any rough edges. Of course, that requires having space _between_ the lathe and the brick for the jig saw blade to move in.